# Number of roots of equation $3^{|x|}-|2-|x||=1$

Tags: functions

Number of roots of equation $3^{|x|}-|2-|x||=1$

**My approach:-**
If $x>0$
$$3^x-2+x=1$$
$$3^x+x=3$$
$$x=3-3^x$$

After this I can't solve this problem

Comment: How did you get from the second line into the third line? The log is not a liner function

Comment: I just take log both sides

Comment: Observe that if $y$ is a solution, so is $-y$

Comment: @AbhishekKumar $log(3^x+x)\ne lon(3^x)+log(x)$

Comment: Desmos shows two roots but I'm pretty sure there are more. This is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can think of this problem in separate cases:

1. $x<-2$
2. $-2\leq x \leq 0$
3. $0\leq x \leq 2$
4. $x>2$

These cases should allow the problem to be enumerated enough to where you can solve for the solution and see if it fits within the assumed domain (otherwise, no solution exists for that case)

Answer (score 1):

Using *only* what you wrote in the last line $$x=3-3^x$$ consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=3^x+x-3$$ The derivatives
$$f'(x)=3^x \log (3)+1 \qquad \qquad  f''(x)=3^x \log ^2(3) > 0 \,\, \forall x$$
Then, the first derivative does not cancel in the real domain and it is always positive. So, ???

In the other hand, by inspection $f(0)=-3$ and $f(1)=+1$; then ???.

Just for your curiosity, there is an analytical expression of the root in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). If you follow the steps given in the linked page, you would get
$$x=3-\frac{W(27 \log (3))}{\log (3)}$$

For the remaining, take into account what is given in comments and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x|=t$. Two cases for $3^t-|2-t|=1$:
$$1) \begin{cases}0\le t<2 \\ 3^t+t-3=0\end{cases} \lor \ 2) \begin{cases} t\ge 2\\ 3^t-t+1=0\end{cases}$$
**Case 1:** the function $f(t)=3^t+t-3$ is increasing:
$$f'(t)=3^t\ln 3+1>0,0\le t<2$$
and $f(0)=-2<f(1)=1$. Hence, there is a solution at $0<t<1$ and $x=\pm t$.

**Case 2:** the function $f(t)=3^t-t+1$ is increasing:
$$f'(t)=3^t\ln 3-1>0,t\ge 2$$
and $f(2)>0$. Hence, there is no solution at $t\ge 2$.

Thus, there are two roots of the original equation:
$$-1<x_1<0 \ \text{and} \ 0<x_2<1$$

Answer (score 0):

How the question is the number of roots. You  can draw two functions 
If $x\geq0$ then $$3^x-1=|2-x|$$

[image]

If $x<0$ then $$3^{-x}-1=|2+x|$$

[image]

There is two roots.

Comment: It's $3^{|x|}$, not $3^x$... Also, I don't think a graph can serve as an answer.

Comment: YuiTo How $3^{|x|}-1=|2-|x||$ then $x\geq0$.

Comment: But what you plot (the orange one) is $|2-x|$, not $|2-|x||...$

Comment: Moreover, notice $3^{|x|}-|2-|x||-1$ is an even function, the number of roots must be even

Comment: YuiTo if $x\geq0$ then $|x|=x$, therefor $3^{|x|}=3^x$, and $|2-|x||=|2-x|$.

Comment: [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tkbzh2gj2g) should be the correct graph. There are actually two solutions, i.e. $-0.742$ and $0.742$.

Comment: Yes, the other case is wend $x<0$, there is other root.